# Updating fields of bits incorrectly

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to solve a question. It says,

> Initialize a new variable to the value 17512807u.
>
> Assume we number the bits as usual from 0 as least significant (on the
>   right) to 31 (most significant, on the left). Update bits 18 through
>   21 with the integer value 8 and bits 10 through 14 with value 17
>   (decimal). Print the resulting value as an eight digit hexadecimal
>   number to show all of the digits.

Here's the code I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int value = 17512807u;
    int L = 21; // starting left position
    int R = 18; // starting right position

    int mask = (1 << (L - R + 1) - 1) << R; 
    int newField = (8 << R) & mask; // integer value 8, shifting to right
    int newValue = value & (~mask); // remove range of bits
    value = newField | newValue; // update range of bits

    L = 14;
    R = 10;

    mask = (1 << (L - R + 1) - 1) << R;
    newField = (17 << R) & mask;
    newValue = value & (~mask);
    value = newField | newValue;

    printf("%08x\n", value);
}
```

The answer I get is 012b7d67

However, I am told this is the incorrect answer. I do not know what the correct answer is.

Comment: The code pasted here didn't even compile for me. Two errors and two warnings. After fixing those, I got 01234567.

Comment: Decimal `17512807` will be hexadecimal `010B3967`.

Comment: Your code can invoke undefined behaviour. `int` is not guaranteed to hold 32 bits. If you need a fixed bit-width, use fixed idth types. Oh, and it is in general better to use unsigned integer when shifting. signed integers can invoke undefined behaviour for certain values (not necessarily true for this example, just keep that in mind!)

Comment: @Olaf I had not noticed that `int value = 17512807u;` does not change `int value` to `unsigned` type.

Answer (score 1):

```
int mask = ((1 << (L - R + 1)) - 1) << R;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expressions to compute `mask` are incorrect. You changed the parentheses in the second expression but both are incorrect, and do not even compile:

```
int mask = ((1 << (L - R + 1) - 1) << R;
...
mask = ((1 << (L - R + 1) - 1 << R);
```

should be written:

```
mask = ((1UL << (L - R + 1)) - 1) << R;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you are asked to do is use the bit fields. For example, given the type

```
struct bits{
    int a:5;
    unsigned short b:3;
    unsigned char c:2;
    bool d:1;
};
```

The above `struct` will have 4 members, each of specific bit length.

If you `union` that struct with an `int` you get a "dual-view" of the bits. As a list of fields *or* as a single integer:

```
union U{
    struct bits fields;
    int i;
};
```

Now the code like

```
U u;
u.i = 0;
u.fields.b = true;
```

becomes valid and gives you access to either the whole number or individual bit fields.