# Updating bit fields in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I'm trying to solve a question that says,

> Initialize a new variable to the value 17512807u.
>
> Assume we number the bits as usual from 0 as least significant (on the
>   right) to 31 (most significant, on the left). Update bits 18 through
>   21 with the integer value 8 and bits 10 through 14 with value 17
>   (decimal). Print the resulting value as an eight digit hexadecimal
>   number to show all of the digits.

I understand what I'm required to do, and my code is working fine, but I'm told that my answer is incorrect.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int value = 17512807u;
    int L = 21; // starting left position
    int R = 18; // starting right position

    int mask = (1 << (L - R + 1) - 1) << R; 
    int newField = (8 << R) & mask; // integer value 8, shifting to right
    int newValue = value & (~mask); // remove range of bits
    value = newField | newValue; // update range of bits

    L = 14;
    R = 10;

    mask = (1 << (L - R + 1) - 1) << R;
    newField = (17 << R) & mask;
    newValue = value & (~mask);
    value = newField | newValue;

    printf("%08x\n", value);
}
```

Since I don't know the correct answer, and the only information I'm given is that my answer is wrong, I do not understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Recently [asked by OP here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42259429/updating-fields-of-bits-incorrectly). Why are you still using `int` type for `17512807u` value after being advised to use `unsigned`?

Comment: @WeatherVane I tried that, it doesn't change anything

Comment: So I guess you will continue to ignore that [good advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42259429/updating-fields-of-bits-incorrectly#comment71677181_42259429) from @Olaf? I do not understand why people ask questions and then carry on blindly.

Comment: The int in this case is guaranteed to be 32-bits. And as I said, I did change it to unsigned and it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you are asked to do is use the bit fields. For example, given the type

```
struct bits{
    int a:5;
    unsigned short b:3;
    unsigned char c:2;
    bool d:1;
};
```

The above `struct` will have 4 members, each of specific bit length.

If you `union` that struct with an `int` you get a "dual-view" of the bits. As a list of fields *or* as a single integer:

```
union U{
    struct bits fields;
    int i;
};
```

Now the code like

```
U u;
u.i = 0;
u.fields.b = true;
```

becomes valid and gives you access to either the whole number or individual bit fields.

Comment: Hmm, I thought the only specified types available for bit field are `_Bool, int, signed int, unsigned int.`  `char c:2` may be a problem.

Comment: May want to post you answer at http://stackoverflow.com/q/42259429/2410359

Comment: Thank you, @chux. Updated the answer and cross-posted it.